# How to set cyphers for imaplib with gmail?

Tags: imaplib

I am using imap with gmail, and I am using the `ssl.create_default_context()` method to set up the SSL connection. I was wondering how I can

1. check what cypher is being used on a given connection started with the IMAP4_SSL constructor
2. ensure that only cyphers from TLSv1.2 or higher are being used.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post what I found to help others doing the same thing. It seems the easiest way to examine the connection is to do packet inspection in wireshark. I followed the steps in [this](https://hussainaliakbar.github.io/restricting-tls-version-and-cipher-suites-in-python-requests-and-testing-with-wireshark/) tutorial. Basically, call ping on your imap server, then put ip.addr ==  as a filter and run your script. Look for the "server hello" tls packet in the list of activity to find the negotiated cypher and protocol version.